# HTML line breaks not rendering properly in the page

Tags: html, jsp

I am using html5 for my JSP. I have a table cell inside which I display text. For new line I added line break tag  but it does not work and it displays line break tag as it is along with my text.

I display it inside my jsp as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <c:out value="${visitInfo.referralText}" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

visitInfo.referralText contains the text.

Comment: Show your rendered HTML, not server code.

Comment: You mean `<` is getting converted to `&lt;` right?

Comment: <BR/> is displayed as it is inside the table cell. This is my html code and not the server side code. it will display the text inside visitInfo.referralText as "Test1<br />Test2"

Comment: @Parag, That's your server-side code because it still has the JSTL tag in it. @isherwood, meant view source in the browser and post that. If you had, you would have seen that `<` was being converted to `&lt;` which is why it showed as `<` in the browser rather than being treated as the beginning of an HTML tag.

Comment: To be fair, the server-side code was helpful, too.

Answer (score 3):

Try with `escapeXml` attribute of `c:out`.

```
<c:out value="${visitInfo.referralText}" escapeXml="false"/>
```

Comment: If the issue is resolved then close the thread by accepting the answer by clicking or right green mark in the answer.